# Content disappear because of the background

Tags: html, css

The content in the website disappeared after changing background position to fixed.

I am trying to display the video background to cover the whole website with the content, because with position absolute it only covers the half of the website then I changed it to position fixed. The content of the website disappeared.

```css
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  color: #505962;
}

.navbar {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
}

.navbar-brand img {
  height: 2rem;
}

.video-background {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.caption {
  position: absolute;
  top: 38%;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark fixed-top">
  <a class="navbar-brand mx-auto" href="index.php">E<img src="wew.png" alt=""> riquez-Survey</a>
</nav>
<div class="video-background">
  <div class="video-wrap">
    <div id="video">
      <video id="bgvid" autoplay loop muted playsinline>
        <source src="stars.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="main-content scene-element scene-element--fade-up">
  <div class="main-section">
    <div class="text-title">Disclaimers</div>
    <p>By participating in this survey, <span class="text-emphasis text-emphasis-notice">you consent to the collection of any data you input into this page</span> to our database(s). Your data will remain anonymous.</p>
    <p>Any information collected is <span class="text-emphasis text-emphasis-notice">for research and educational purposes only</span> and will not be sold or freely given. However, the results of the survey <span class="text-emphasis text-emphasis-notice">will be publicly accessible</span>      through this website.</p>
    <p>Please note that <span class="text-emphasis text-emphasis-notice">this survey is entirely voluntary</span>. If you are unwilling to participate in this survey or are offended in one way or another by its contents, you are free to exit this website
      without consequence to yourself.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to display a video background that covers whole page when I scroll down and display all the content on it.

Answer (score 1):

Your video should be at the top of your HTML, that way it is the first element to be draw, and therefore completely at the back.

Then you still have to make sure other things are positioned on top of it, by also setting their position to `fixed`. You would normally use something that also covers the whole window.

For an example see: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/KIKO_Software/uzvc75bk/7) or [How TO - Fullscreen Video](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_fullscreen_video.asp)